# Add title to image tag

Tags: joomla-3.x, images, media-manager

[image]
Seo optimizers cannot find titles in pictures, and I can not find how to add it through the admin panels. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what the screenshot is supposed to show and what is the context. Where do you add those images?

When editing a Joomla article, you can add images through the Images tab, and there you can add a title attribute to the image through the Caption field.

[image: Joomla Article Images]

If you are adding an image through in the content via the core Editor, then you can add a title through the Image Title Field.

[image: Joomla Editor Image Panel]

If you are using JCE Editor, then via the JCE Image manager you Advanced Tab you can add a title to the inserted image.

[image]

---